# Is this possible to valid the domain is belongs to somebody?

Tags: validation, dns, subdomain

For example, I have a field that give user to type their domain, the user can type any domain on this, but I don't valid this domain is belong that user. Of course, I can generate a random number text file for user to upload, and when I get the random number text file, if it is match, I can just treat it as a valid domain holder. But, except from this method, is that anyway to do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options I have seen:

- Have user Create a Text file in document root, check for it
- Send Email to contacts listed in whois (Or other ROLE type accounts (postmaster, hostmaster, etc...), with token they need to
  return
- Have them create an 'A' record in their DNS that is unique and you can query for.

There really isn't any other way of telling if they have control over the domain.  Using whois information isn't 100% accurate as  people don't update it, or their info isn't registered to them, or is hidden behind something like domains by proxy.  There is no standard information in DNS, that can tell you ownership.  Since google uses the DNS method and the text file method (I think), you can probably safely assume that is a good way to verify it.